# Intermittent failure of onFormSubmit trigger

Tags: forms, triggers

We are a small school district and I have written a simple form for teachers to report disciplinary problems.  The destination spreadsheet has a script bound to it and an [onFormSubmit](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_8vgDqOjyb3Y1dvdnhGQ0xOU3c/view?usp=sharing) trigger is set.

The script uses the form data using the event object e from the function onFormSubmit(), creates a report in Google Docs, send email notices to relevant people and does a few maintenance tasks. [Link](https://script.google.com/d/1SNInTWMR5A5PZQCdbXTbk4VYHET1YP6aKs9d_tLvraG7GzejdF5Gol9g/edit?usp=sharing) to code.

It's been working fine until recently when the trigger occasionally fails to fire.  No error message; the form data is submitted.  This morning, two teachers in separate incidents entered a form and the trigger failed; a third entered the form and it worked.

The form and sheet are 'owned' by the Dean of Students account and users access the form anonymously on the network (not in Google account).  The form is set with VIEW privilege for anyone with a link; the sheet has no privileges, only owner.

I am completely stumped as to why this would work sometimes and not others.  Clues?

Comment: You should probably include your code in the question, or as much as is necessary to reproduce or investigate your issue. You, as the author, can still "edit" the post.

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed a Google Spreadsheet with multiple sheets that takes data from 4 different forms. When the form data comes in, I have scripts that run multiple calculations and formatting on that data, so the onFormSubmit trigger is crucial for me. I've come across the exact same problem you are having right now.

At first I thought there was something wrong with my code and I checked it over and over again. Then, I scoured the web for answers to why my triggers failed about 10 to 20% of the time. A lot of what I found on Google forums related to problems from Google's side. I found that [tons of people](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3969) faced the same problem I had, but none of them had a definitive fix.

My eventual solution was to create yet another trigger that fires every 8 hours. This runs everything my other triggers run yet again just to make sure everything I wanted to do has been done. Of course, that trigger could fail, too. But so far, I've been checking the sheet (new data comes in about every 6 hours or so) and I haven't had to fix any problems whereas before, I had to rerun scripts daily.

Maybe for your case, you can have a function that goes through and sends emails that previous faulty triggers failed to send. Then have this function fire every however many hours you prefer.

This is probably not a very satisfying answer but it's the best I can do. Good luck!